# Use a class to handle shared state in a non-trivial sequence of functions

Tags: c++

I need to perform non-trivial I/O operations with several devices in a predetermined sequence.

State (non-trivial too) needs to be maintained in the sequence, and I would rather not pass it as a parameter to the functions, if I can avoid it: manipulating `a` is less cumbersome than manipulating `state.a`. Also, encapsulating state and computation on that state in a class seems like one of the main points of object oriented design.

This would lead to something like the following (solution 1).

Header file:

```
/**
 * module.h
 */
void io_sequence();
```

Implementation file:

```
/**
 * module.cpp
 */

// Helper class, not visible outside this file
class Helper {
public:
  Helper();
  void help() { step1(); step2(); step3(); }
private:
  void step1();
  void step2();
  void step3();

  int a;
  ComplexType b;
  vector<ComplexType2> c;
};

// Implementation of Helper...

// Implementation of the public function
void io_sequence()
{
  // The following two lines could be replaced by Helper().help();
  Helper helper;
  helper.help();
}
```

This will work, but why not the following instead (solution 2)?

Header file:

```
/**
 * module.h
 */
void io_sequence();
```

Implementation file:

```
/**
 * module.cpp
 */

// Helper class, not visible outside this file.
// Invoked like a function.
class help {
public:
  help() { step1(); step2(); step3(); }
private:
  void step1();
  void step2();
  void step3();

  int a;
  ComplexType b;
  vector<ComplexType2> c;
};

// Implementation of help...

// Implementation of the public function
void io_sequence()
{
  (void) help();
}
```

I would just go for solution 2, but I cannot find any reference to that pattern on the Internet. I guess that means that it would be frowned upon.

Is solution 2 bad and in that case, what do you recommend instead, or is it just fine?

Note that I had earlier asked [a similar question for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064953/using-a-class-as-a-container-object-for-local-variables-as-an-alternative-to-no), and the accepted solution there seemed to indicate that solution 2 for Python was fine (clean according to @jsbueno).

Comment: You do not need ` (void)` as a prefix to your `help()`. Overall, I see no problem with solution 2.

Comment: @user463035818 compiles just fine. You do not need an instance.

Comment: @user463035818 I have just double-checked, and solution 2 compiles fine. Try it if you do not believe it (replace the ComplexTypes by ints). You seems to miss the point. `help()` _is_ an instantiation.

Comment: yes it compiles, sorry I misread your code.

Comment: @user463035818 On the other hand `help()` in solution 1 or 2 cannot be made static, since it invokes non-static member functions.

Comment: @SergeyA thanks for your approval.

Comment: @Bitwize solution 2 without `(void)` generates no warnings whatsoever. It is not a variable declaration, since the object remains anonymous.

Comment: @SergeyA I agree `(void)` is not needed. I just use it to document that I disregard the object returned by the constructor on purpose.

Comment: @user463035818 I do consider firing two incorrect comments in no time without taking the time to understand the question as disrespectful, and therefore unwelcoming.

Comment: Full disclosure: I didn't downvote the question, but I voted to close it as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @drescherm quoting the manual: "when should I vote down? Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post". Nothing to do with the subjective "no useful in helping future readers".

Comment: @SergeyA I respect the opinion-based argument. My feeling is that whether or not solution 2 could be considered a pattern is dependent on the proportion of people in the community who are aware of the fact that classes in C++ can be used (abused?) in that manner. Solution 2 looks like a function call, which is exactly what the invoker wants (superior to `Helper helper; helper.help()`if you ask me). It is only obfuscated if people are not used to it. Isn't pattern discussion a part of StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more obvious solution that comes to my mind now, since I had already decided to hide the class entirely in the function's implementation file, is to take out the sequence logic from the class and put it directly in the function instead. I was first opposed to that, as a matter of principle (encapsulation), but I now think it makes sense, especially comparing this idea to making the function a friend of the class (making the function a friend of the class would give it access to all private members, which is not necessary).

Header file:

```
/**
 * module.h
 */
void sequence();
```

Implementation file:

```
/**
 * module.cpp
 */

// Helper class, not visible outside this file
class Helper {
public:
  Helper();
  void step1();
  void step2();
  void step3();

private:
  int a;
  ComplexType b;
  vector<ComplexType2> c;
};

// Implementation of Helper...

// Implementation of the public function
void sequence()
{
  Helper helper;
  helper.step1();
  helper.step2();
  helper.step3();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that @user463035818 in one of his deleted comments to my original question might have meant something like the following (in my defense, nothing was said in the comment about creating an instance of the class in a static member function):

Everything in the header file, and trivialized code, for brevity:

```
/*
 * Helper.h
 */
class Helper {
public:
    static void help() { Helper h; h.step1(); h.step2(); h.step3(); }
private:
    Helper() {}
    void step1(){}
    void step2(){}
    void step3(){}

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

Use directly, no intermediary function abstracting the class:

```
/*
 * main.cpp
 */
int main()
{
    Helper::help();
}
```